# Enable macro depending on cmake target

Tags: c++, macros, cmake

I'm trying to enable a C-Macro only when the corresponding source file is used by a specific cmake target. Assume I have the following setup:

```
tests/test.cpp
src/code.cpp
include/code.hpp
CMakeList.txt
```

code.hpp

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void normal_stuff();
#ifdef TEST
    int debug;
    void _dangerous_function()
    {
         debug++;
    }
#endif
}
```

code.cpp

```
#include "code.hpp"

MyClass::normal_stuff()
{
    // boring code
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include "code.hpp"

void some_test()
{
    MyClass foo;
    foo._dangerous_function();
}
```

CMakeList.txt

```
project(foo)
include_directories(include)
file(GLOB_RECURSE foo_source src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE test_source test/*.cpp)
add_executeable(foo ${foo_source})
add_executeable(test ${test_source} ${foo_source})
```

I want to set TEST only when *code.cpp* is build for the test target, but not for the foo target. Of course I could just write "#define TEST" in *test.cpp* before I include *code.hpp*, but then *code.cpp* will have a different view of MyClass than *test.cpp*.

Has anyone an idea how I could do that? I know, I *shouldn't* be doing this, but I would like to know, if I could get it running at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may set a target specific property to add such definition:

```
set_target_properties(test PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "TEST")
```

read more [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aset_target_properties) and [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aCOMPILE_DEFINITIONS)

Answer (score 0):

Another more specific (and shorter) way of achieving this is using [target_compile_definition](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.23/command/target_compile_definitions.html):

```
target_compile_definitions(test PUBLIC TEST)
```